# FireBaseRecyclerAdapter is not displaying in Android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

My firebaserecyclerView is not showing in the app but the data is added in firebase structure

Here is my Firebase structure

[image]

I need to display the expenses name and total in recyclerview

**Main Activity**

```
public class DayExpensesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Expenses,ExpenseViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
Query query;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_day_expenses);
recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    final Expenses expensesDate = new Expenses(username, monthyr, currentdate);
    query=databaseReference.child("users").child(expensesDate.getUsername()).child(expensesDate.getMonth()).child(expensesDate.getDate());
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Expenses> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Expenses>()
                    .setQuery(query, Expenses.class)
                    .build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Expenses, ExpenseViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExpenseViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Expenses model) {
            holder.expensesText.setText(model.getExpenseName());
            holder.totaltext.setText(model.getTotal());


      @NonNull
        @Override
        public ExpenseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.expenses_card_layout,parent,false);

            return new ExpenseViewHolder(view);
        }
    };

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

**ExpensesViewHolder**

```
public class ExpenseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

public TextView expensesText,totaltext;
public ImageButton addBtn,editBtn;

private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener){
    this.itemClickListener=itemClickListener;
}

public ExpenseViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    expensesText=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.expensestext);
    totaltext=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.totaltxt);
    addBtn=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
    editBtn=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_edt);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    itemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition(),false);

}
}
```

Comment: Have you start listening for changes?

Comment: Ya I have added startListening() but still its not showing

Comment: What are values of username, monthyr, currentdate?

Comment: As you see in my firebase strcuture its child node which i get from previous activity  and need to display only the expenses name and total in recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply display those two values, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference ref = databaseReference
    .child("users")
    .child(expensesDate.getUsername())
    .child("Expenses")
    .child(expensesDate.getMonth())
    .child(expensesDate.getDate());
```

Now you can add a listener to read those values:

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String expenseName = dataSnapshot.child("expenseName").getValue(String.class);
            String total = dataSnapshot.child("total").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", expenseName + " / " + total);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
pegrol / 76
```

There is no need to display those values in a `RecyclerView` because a RecyclerView is used to recycle views and in your case there is no need to recycle a single view.

Comment: i have used recyclerview  because user can add expenses total whenever their need .so total will get recycle whenever user add extra total to it.The present total will get add to new total and it need to display

Comment: It's a difference between the recycle concept and refresh a view. Did my above code work?

Comment: No it passing as null

Comment: What is passing as `null`?

Comment: Expenses name and total is passing as null in Log

Comment: Please edit your question by adding the changed code.

Comment: Hi Padma! Is there everything alright, have you solved the issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply..i am facing another issue .I am unable open android studio and i have set my environment path still it didnt work .So i have downloaded newer version Android studio 3.1 but it automatically closes Do you have any solution for it.Thanks

Comment: This sounds as another question that cannot be answered in a comment. To follow the rules of this community, please post another question so me or other users can help you.

Comment: Please see this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626325/listview-is-not-showing-populating-from-firebase?noredirect=1#comment92186438_52626325] @Alex Mamo